# What is the difference between these two rememberSaveable calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my app I have a screen for entering various parameters that are saved to a Room Database. To ensure that the values are preserved if the screen is navigated away from I'm using Flow from my Room Database to maintain state. In my code you will see one of the rememberSaveable calls commented out. If I change it out with the other call the functionality is the same. They both work and I can navigate away from this screen and back to it and the current value is maintained. I had read that longer method is preferred. Something about supplying a key. I'm new to all of this and trying to understand and use best practices.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BuyInSection(
    sessionViewModel: SessionViewModel,
    sessionId: Long,
    buyInError: Boolean,
) {
    val session by sessionViewModel.currentValues.collectAsState()
    val (buyIn, setBuyIn) = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(session.buyIn) }
   // val (buyIn, setBuyIn) = rememberSaveable(session.buyIn) { mutableStateOf(session.buyIn) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Buy In",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .background(if (buyInError) Color.Red else Color.White)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = buyIn.toString(),
            onValueChange = { setBuyIn(it.toIntOrNull() ?: 0) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
        Button(
            enabled = sessionViewModel.isSessionRunning.value,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f),
            onClick = {
                sessionViewModel.updateAttribute(
                    sessionId.toInt(),
                    SessionAttribute.BUY_IN,
                    SessionRepository.IntValue(buyIn))
                if (buyInError) sessionViewModel.completeSession()
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Enter Buy In")
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried both methods and they both work, but what is preferred and why.

Added viewModel and updated UI module

```kotlin
class SessionViewModel(application: Application): ViewModel() {
    private var sessionRepository: SessionRepository

    init {
        val sessionDb = SessionRoomDatabase.getInstance(application)
        val sessionDao = sessionDb.SessionDao()
        sessionRepository = SessionRepository(sessionDao)
    }

    private val _sessionId = MutableStateFlow<Long>(0)
    val sessionId: MutableStateFlow<Long> = _sessionId

    private val _incompleteValues = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<String>())
    val incompleteValues: StateFlow<List<String>> = _incompleteValues

    private var _timeUnit = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val timeUnit: MutableStateFlow<Int> = _timeUnit

    fun setTimeAmount(amount: Int) {
        _timeUnit.value = amount
    }

    private val _elapsedTimeText =   MutableStateFlow("")
    val elapsedTimeText: MutableStateFlow<String> = _elapsedTimeText

    private val _startTimeText = MutableStateFlow("Press to start session time")
    val startTimeText: MutableStateFlow<String> = _startTimeText

    @OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
    fun startSessionTimer() {
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        val formatted = current.format(formatter)
        updateAttribute(sessionId.value.toInt(),
            SessionAttribute.START_TIME,
            SessionRepository.StringValue(formatted))

        _startTimeText.value = formatted
        val startTime = TimeSource.Monotonic.markNow()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            while (isSessionRunning.value) {
                delay(1000)
                _elapsedTimeText.value = startTime.elapsedNow().inWholeSeconds.seconds.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    fun getAll(): List<Session> {
        return sessionRepository.getAll()
    }

    //When add cash session is called, a new session is created and inserted into the database
    //The session id is then returned and used to update the session attributes
    //Also calls getCurrentValues to update the UI with the current values
    private fun insertAll(session: Session) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _sessionId.value = sessionRepository.insertAll(session)
            getCurrentValues()
        }
    }

    fun addCashSession() {
        val session = Session()
        session.location = ""
        session.startTime = ""
        session.endTime = ""
        session.buyIn = 0
        session.addOn = 0
        session.rakePaid = 0
        session.timePaid = 0
        session.tipsPaid = 0
        session.jackpotPaid = 0
        session.cashOut = 0
        session.gameId = 0
        session.notes = ""

        insertAll(session)
    }

    fun updateAttribute(id: Int, attributeName: SessionAttribute, newValue: SessionRepository.AttributeValue) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            sessionRepository.updateAttribute(id, attributeName, newValue)
        }
    }

    // isSessionRunning is a MutableStateFlow that holds the current session running state.
    private val _isSessionRunning = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isSessionRunning: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = _isSessionRunning

    fun setIsSessionRunning(isRunning: Boolean) {
        _isSessionRunning.value = isRunning
    }

    // getById is a Flow that holds the current session database values.
    private fun getById(id: Int): Flow<Session> {
        return sessionRepository.getById(id)
    }

    //completeSession is called when the session is complete. Checks to see if there are any
    //incomplete values and updates the UI accordingly with red background.
    fun completeSession() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val session = getById(sessionId.value.toInt()).first()
            _incompleteValues.value = session.incompleteAttributes()
            isSessionRunning.value = incompleteValues.value.isNotEmpty()
        }
    }

    // CurrentValues is a MutableStateFlow that holds the current session database values.
    // It is initialized when a new session is started.
    private var _currentValues = MutableStateFlow(Session())
    val currentValues: MutableStateFlow<Session> = _currentValues

    private fun getCurrentValues() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getById(sessionId.value.toInt()).collect { session ->
                _currentValues.value = session
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun BuyInSection(
    sessionViewModel: SessionViewModel,
    isSessionRunning: Boolean,
    sessionId: Long,
    session: Session,
    incompleteValues: List<String>
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Buy In",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .background(if (incompleteValues.contains("buyIn")) Color.Red else Color.White)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            enabled = isSessionRunning,
            value = session.buyIn.toString(),
            onValueChange = { sessionViewModel.updateAttribute(sessionId.toInt(),
                SessionAttribute.BUY_IN,
                SessionRepository.IntValue(it.toIntOrNull() ?: 0))
                if (incompleteValues.contains("buyIn")) sessionViewModel.completeSession() },
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use `remember` to keep an instance from recreate from recomposition

```
val (buyIn, setBuyIn) = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(session.buyIn) }
```

But, when you can pass one or more arguments as inputs, each time that input has changed, your state will be reset and the init block will run again.

```
val (buyIn, setBuyIn) = rememberSaveable(session.buyIn) { mutableStateOf(session.buyIn) }
```

In your code, each time session.buyIn changes its value, your `buyIn` state will be recreated.

IMPORTANT:
Because your `session.buyIn` is a `StateFlow` and it is controlled by a `ViewModel`, which can survive configuration changes or any other restart-effect. So both of your above declarations are unnecessary.
One more advice to get better compose-performance, your model should be immutable

UPDATED: `BuyInSection`

```
@Composable
fun BuyInSection(
    isSessionRunningProvider: () -> Boolean,
    session: Session,
    isIncompleteValuesProvider: () -> Boolean,
    onSessionBuiltInValueChanged: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    val isSessionRunning = isSessionRunningProvider()
    val isIncompleteValues = isIncompleteValuesProvider()
    val (buyIn, setBuyIn) = remember(key1 = session) {
        mutableStateOf(session.buyIn.toString())
    }
    val onSessionBuiltInValueChangedFunc = remember(onSessionBuiltInValueChanged) {
        { value: String ->
            setBuyIn(value)
            onSessionBuiltInValueChanged(value)
        }
    }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Buy In",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .background(if (isIncompleteValues) Color.Red else Color.White)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            enabled = isSessionRunning,
            value = buyIn,
            onValueChange = onSessionBuiltInValueChangedFunc,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I updated my code to only use session.buyin and it seems to work nicely. In my outlinedTextField I replaced buyin to session.buyin for value and onValueChange now updates the database directly with sessionViewModel.updateAttribute(sessionId.toInt(), SessionAttribute.BUY_IN, SessionRepository.IntValue(buyIn)). This actually eliminates the need for the button. Is there anything wrong with this approach.

Comment: Can you show your viewmodel too?

Comment: I've added the viewModel and updated UI module. It seems to work well. The only issue I have run into is the UI module that takes notes. It sometimes doesn't update fast enough.  Could be solved by using a button to update database.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know your `session.buyIn` is not a state-flow. So please see my updated answer